# Border around edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I read so many similar issues on this site.  However, I cant seem to find a solution to work for me. The background of my app is black and now when I add the red border, the edit text box is also black.  I used transparent or #000000 and the background of my edit text is still black and I want the default white.  Below code also made my edit text size narrow.  Please help.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ffff0000" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this error is occurring is because the xml code `"@android:color/transparent"` does exactly that, makes the background of the view in question transparent/see through. So by you entering that text, the background of the view is invisible, and you see the app's colour.

In order to get the white background you wish for, it would only be necessary for you to change the `"@android:color/transparent"` **to** `android:color="#ffffff"`. That code segment will change the color to white.